# How do we get the exact content offset for the scrollview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I would like to set the content offset in the scrollview so that it doesn't scroll beyond the last button in the scrollview. Now its scroll even beyond that and thats not a good UI. I would like to know how we can limit the content offset based on the elements in the screen.

Comment: There is a property called `contentOffset` on `UIScrollView`. You might also want to look at how the `contentSize` is being set, it sounds like your content size might not match your actual content.

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks Dennis